# raspi-io development on x64

Tags: node.js

I'm new to the Raspberry PI world. I want to develop a NodeJS application but don't want to the development on the Raspberry itself, just use it to run the app.

When I try to run `npm i raspy-io` on my Mac I get

```
error raspi-gpio@6.2.2: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
error Found incompatible module.
```

How do you do it?

Thanks

Comment: You need a dummy module here: Something that implements the API surface, but does nothing.  There may or may not be something of that sort around already.  If not, it shouldn't be too hard to write one, all you need are no-op functions with the right signature.

Answer (score 2):

One alternate way is to use Visual Studio Code from Microsoft [(details here)](https://code.visualstudio.com) residing on the Mac and connect a Pi 3B (or any 4 core Pi) to the Mac via Ethernet / RNDIS or WiFi.

VS Code (not to be mixed up with Visual Studio) can then install a remote debugger to execute and control your programs on the Pi.

Using NETATALK you can then pull any code files back over to the Mac and include them in a TimeMachine backup.  I used CarbonCopy to push/pull files from my Pi at regular intervals.

Once everything is configured I then use ApplePI Baker to image the SD card as this compresses any empty space (basically zips the image) as a final backup.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi has a 64 Bit ARM Cpu (but runs with a 32 Bit OS by default). So you need to make sure you build your program for ARM, 32bit.

Comment: Sorry I don't see how that would answer my question.

Comment: I am not a node user, but there is a good chance this is simply not possible because the source code itself will not be portable -- the gpio code will be based on some Pi-specific library that can't be ported either.

Comment: @MelkorNemesis Oh, sorry I haven't read correctly. Apparently your problem is the other way round. You seem to be trying to import the raspy-io module on the Mac, but it doesn't find an x64 implementation for that. I'm also not familiar with node, but goldilocks is probably right: You either need a dummy implementation to test / build the code on the Mac or perform a cross-compilation somehow.

Comment: `The Raspberry Pi has a 64 Bit ARM Cpu` not the pi0, pi1 or early pi2

Answer (score 1):

You need to either mock the GPIO calls or use remote GPIO.

The [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) python library provides a "mock" pin interface so you can run GPIO code on any machine.

It also provides a remote GPIO option so you can run on a PC but control the pins on a Pi on the network (this is via the pigpio daemon so you can do this from any language with a pigpio client library - e.g. [npm/pigpio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pigpio)).

Obviously you won't be using gpiozero but this is just to highlight what needs to be done to make it possible. I don't know of a NodeJS mock GPIO library but if you look for one you might find one.

Alternatively of course, you can work remotely on the Pi - SSH, VNC or whatever.